# Javascript object property reset not working

Tags: javascript, object, reset

I have a javascript object called myObject. Inside that object i have a property called x that has a value of 0. After i have incremented x value by 1 i want to reset it back to 0, without accessing x to change it,  but it does not work for some reason. I am using the Module Pattern.

```
var MyObject = (function(){

return {
     x:0
}
})();

var myObject = MyObject;

myObject.x+=1;
console.log(myObject.x); // shows value of 1

myObject = MyObject;  // object property reset
console.log(myObject.x); // shows value of 1, but i want 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not resetting your object. You need to call the function each time.

```
var MyObject = (function() {
  return {
    x: 0
  }
});

var myObject = MyObject();
myObject.x += 1;
console.log(myObject.x); // shows value of 1

myObject = MyObject(); // object property reset
console.log(myObject.x); // shows value of 0
```

Comment: This answer is *wrong*. OP is using an IIFE to assign a value to `MyObject` and therefore the value of `MyObject` is not a function and consequently trying to do `myObject = MyObject();` will result in `TypeError: MyObject is not a function`

Comment: @rabbitco In this example, although the function is inside parentheses (expression), it is not being invoked, so MyObject gets assigned the value that expression evaluates to, which is indeed a function.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp: That is incorrect. OP code is `var MyObject = (function() {return {x: 0}})();`. So it *is* invoked. Copy paste OP's code and run it and you will see for yourself.

Comment: Yes it is, but in this answer it is not. That's what I meant, this answer actually should work.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp: ok you are right about that. But the answer leaves the impression that OP - in his own code - just needs to change `myObject = MyObject;` to `myObject = MyObject();` and that won't work.

Comment: Besides why is the function encapsulated in `()` - that makes no sense. I think SoftwareEngineer just did a poor job of copy-pasting OP's code ...

Comment: @rabbitco I agree it is a little confusing, and those parens better not be there either.

Answer (score 2):

> Javascript object reset not working

That is because you are re-assigning a reference to the same object.

### What your are overlooking in your code

You are using an [IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) to initially assign the value `{x: 0}` to `MyObject`. You are **not** assigning a function to `MyObject`:

```
var MyObject = (function() {
  return {
    x: 0
  }
})();

console.log(MyObject); // { x: 0 }
```

That is because the IIFE only executes once and then ceases to exist. When you then do `var myObject = MyObject;` you are **not** creating a copy of `MyObject` but just another reference to the object `{ x: 0 }`:

```
var a = {x: 0};
var b = a;

console.log(b); // {x: 0}

b.x = 10;

console.log (a); // 10
console.log (b); // 10
```

That is why your `myObject = MyObject;` does not reset anything because you are actually just restating that `myObject` should point to the same object as `MyObject`.

### How you can make it work

Change your code to:

```
var MyObject = function(){
    return {x: 0}
}

var myObject = MyObject();

myObject.x+=1;
console.log(myObject.x); // 1

myObject = MyObject();  
console.log(myObject.x); // 0
```